# After upgrading from 13.10 to 14.04 LTS Intel drivers not loading only Gallium 0.4

Tags: xorg

So this morning I was informed of the 14.04 LTS release and asked if I wanted to upgrade. I performed the upgrade process and all went fine, but when I checked the video drivers after the upgrade was complete I saw "Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.4, 256 bits)" instead of the normal "Intel Sandybridge Mobile".

Naturally of course the XOrg website shows that the Linux-Intel-Grphics-Installer is not yet updated for the 14.04 release.

Is there any way for me to get my proper drivers working, or am I stuck waiting until Intel decides to release the updated installer? It took them months for the 13.10 release, so I'm hoping for something faster.

Update:
Looks like the problem is that when the XServer starts up it attempts to load the intel module but that fails so it reverts back to the Gallium.

From my XOrg.0.log

```
 [    25.073] Loading extension GLX
 [    25.073] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
 [    25.073] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module intel
 [    25.073] (II) UnloadModule: "intel"
 [    25.073] (II) Unloading intel
 [    25.073] (EE) Failed to load module "intel" (module does not exist, 0)
 [    25.073] (==) Matched intel as autoconfigured driver 0
 [    25.073] (==) Matched intel as autoconfigured driver 1
 [    25.073] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 2
 [    25.073] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 3
 [    25.073] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 4
 [    25.073] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
 [    25.073] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
 [    25.074] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module intel
 [    25.074] (II) UnloadModule: "intel"
 [    25.074] (II) Unloading intel
 [    25.074] (EE) Failed to load module "intel" (module does not exist, 0)
```

So if anyone can give me a hint as to why XServer can't load this, or why it says it doesn't exist that would be nice. I was led to believe that there are Intel drivers in the actual Ubuntu releases.

Comment: If you are not facing any graphics problem then that would be your last option until they release for Ubuntu 14.04 :)

Comment: Sadly I can't play Minecraft with these drivers. I only get about 10 FPS when I'm usually getting 30-60. That's a big drop.

Comment: I had just "upgraded" from 13.10 to 14.04 (Lubuntu). I got no errors, but when I restarted my computer, after entering my password, I find no launch bar, no menu, and nothing (other than cntrl-alt-F1) seems to work. Is it a graphics problem? How do I get back to using (L)ubuntu? This is really frustrating and pathetic...

Comment: do you have a `xorg.conf` file? Or installed some other driver? I highly doubt the graphics are complete, and maybe [you need to report a bug.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) or just install from scratch :P

Comment: The OS builds its own xorg.conf file apparently. It looks to be fine, so I'm guessing that somehow the driver is just not there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have figured out the problem. Apparently something didn't upgrade correctly for the xserver-xorg-video-intel packages.

So I followed the selected answer of this package [How reinstall the default graphics drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80914/how-reinstall-the-default-graphics-drivers) which fixed the problem.

Basically I reinstalled the packages and restarted the computer (it should be noted that the final terminal call `unity --restart` is deprecated, so I simply restarted the computer). Once reinstalled and restarted the Sandybridge was visible in my System Settings-->Details section and my FPS returned to normal.

Comment: Thx for the link :) it works!

Answer (score 2):

Intel hasn't updated their graphics stack just yet.  However, 14.04 comes with mesa10, so you should get the same performance.  I do with my hd4000

Comment: Sadly not when I'm playing Minecraft.

Comment: Either way, Intel have not yet updated their graphics stack for 14.04.  It should be soon though, but in the meantime you may have to wait it out.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem when I upgrade Xubuntu from 14.04.4 to 16.04.1 .
Solution:

```
aptitude versions xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

look lines with "c" begins and install **xserver-xorg-video-intel** with latest version,
for example:

```
aptitude install xserver-xorg-video-intel=2:2.99.917+git20160325-1ubuntu1
```