# Nothing after logging into account

Tags: 14.04, command-line, crash, logging

I tried to install java and few other upgrades, so I found this website:
http://itsfoss.com/things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu-14-04/

and did basically everything. After reboot screen with the encryption password has a small resolution, later logging screen is normal and after password and enter I just see the wallpaper and my mouse. I made before hotkeys for task manager and xkill but non of them works, either ctrl+alt+t
Guest session doesn't work also.

please help me.. I'm fighting with linux for over a week :( I just try to make it working and leave it like it is

Things I have done:

- I have installed Nvidia drivers (official and tested)
- I updated software with canonical partners
- Installed Play encrypted DVD in Ubuntu 14.04 by: 
  `sudo apt-get install libdvdread4
  sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh`
- Installed rar `sudo apt-get install rar`
- Installed TLP
  `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw
  sudo tlp start`
- Installed Tweak Unity `sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool`
- Disabled shopping suggestions
  `gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Lenses disabled-scopes "['more_suggestions-amazon.scope', 'more_suggestions-u1ms.scope', 'more_suggestions-populartracks.scope', 'music-musicstore.scope', 'more_suggestions-ebay.scope', 'more_suggestions-ubuntushop.scope', 'more_suggestions-skimlinks.scope']"` <- however something was wrong, didn't get the part with ebay-scope.
- Installed java `sudo apt-get install icedtea-7-plugin openjdk-7-jre`

Edit:
I read [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/382455/335321) that similar thing can happen when installed nvidia drivers without having nvidia, however I do have 720M and I have no idea how to write commands without logging in.

Edit2: Logged in the root terminal in recovery mode, tried `sudo apt-get remove unity-tweak-tool` but it doesn't work. `Not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock`

Edit3: I stopped messing with the recover (didn't know how does it work like) and I have logged in with `ctrl+alt+f1`. For other newbies like me: my login is from the capital letter, but here I had to write it from a small one :)
I typed `sudo apt-get remove unity-tweak-tool` but it didn't help..
Should I use `unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity` ? I don't want to configure everything again if there is other option

Edit4: Installed both of these [jockey-common and ubuntu-drivers-common](https://askubuntu.com/questions/335285/how-to-change-proprietary-video-driver-using-the-command-line) but non of the commands works. (--list)

`sudo apt-get install nvidia-current` stops on 26% Unable to fetch some archives. `apt-get update` didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it on my own! :)
Maybe someone will use it.

Answer is [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/81039/335321), however second and third line didn't work for me. As always some archive problem. Neverthless it was because of the nvidia, I will never move it again.

`sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-intel libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
sudo update-alternatives --remove gl_conf /usr/lib/nvidia-current/ld.so.conf`

But I made a new problem, I can't change brightness at all. Is there any end of configuring this system..?