# Brightness was working but I reinstalled drivers

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, brightness

In the morning only buttons didn't work, now even through the settings. I did few [updates](https://askubuntu.com/questions/536935/nothing-after-logging-into-account) today and as a result I had to reinstall drivers. Now I cannot change my brightness in any way..

14.04
nvidia geforce 720M
at the moment open source drivers, 331 prop, tested gave me an error that took me 2h to repair..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't really say which answer helped me. I made today 20 different things and nothing worked after reboots.

Installing Brightness Controller was a cheating solution which I accepted when I had enough.
One of the tips made me install some small program and add hot keys for the brightness. I try to refresh website after few hours and I start  lowering brightness (I made F5 to lower it).