# Partially blank screen in Lubuntu 16.04.4 LTS

Tags: 16.04, lubuntu, display

I installed Lubuntu 16.04.4 LTS on an old netbook.
Upon rebooting I had issues with grub that were fixed with boot-repair.
Now when I boot the screen is only partially usable (about 20% to the tight hand side), see image.
[image: partially working display] 
When the mouse cursor is in the OK part of the screen, I can do a right click and click on the icons in the bottom (battery, network and sound).  If I click on the shutdown icon, the screen goes darker and the icon becomes grey, I can no longer click on it.

The display is just fine when running Lubuntu from the USB stick, and also OK (though incorrect screen resolution) in recovery mode.

The Netbook is an Acer Aspire One from 2009, please let me know what info I should supply about it.

Google did not help as I'm finding mostly posts about blank screens, not partially failed screens.
Any suggestions will be most gratefully received, I apologise if it's something obvious, have mercy, I have been a Linux user for 20 years, but I'm none the wiser when it comes to trouble shooting.

Comment: An update to kernel 4.13.0.37 made no difference.

Comment: If I start with an external display connected to the VGA port, then there's no issue, both displays are recognised and used, _even when the VGA display is off_.  If I connect the display after I've started, I have to use 'xrandr' then once the VGA display is used, that sets the laptop display right.

Answer (score 0):

I've had to troubleshoot similar graphical issues in the past where I've made major changes to my setup.  Nine times out of ten it's been the Nvidia drivers causing the problem.  Maybe it's the case for you too?

You could try:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-intel libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
sudo update-alternatives --remove gl_conf /usr/lib/nvidia-current/ld.so.conf
```

And then reboot afterwards.

I got the above from [How reinstall the default graphics drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80914/how-reinstall-the-default-graphics-drivers) which looks very similar to what I've used in the past.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks but that did not work.  The nvidia-* purge found nothing.  Then when I came to reconfigure xserver-org it was not installed.

Comment: Have you tried restarting your display manager? 
`sudo service lightdm restart`

Comment: Yes, I tried that too, it does not work.  Thanks for trying though.